# SSHD Crashing after glibc upgrade

Tags: sshd

[image]

Hi,
I made a yum update on 18th of july:

[image]

After that sshd is crashing on startup, Any help?

Answer (score 1):

Please post log excerpts as text.  I see this:

```
error: Bind to port 22 on :: failed: Address already in use.
```

This means some other process is already listening on port 22/TCP.  It could be an existing instance of sshd that systemd somehow failed to track, or a different kind of SSH server (dropbear?).  You can use `lsof -n` or `ss -p -l -t` to find that process, and them run `systemctl status PID` with the PID value to find out where it's coming from.

Comment: Can you add the output from the `ss -p -l -t` command to your post?

Comment: Florian Weimer.. i must in this way (i uploaded image in new answer).. sorry can't copy/paste from console

Comment: I tried to access few second after reboot and it lets me in. And:

[root@goautodial-7 ~]# systemctl status sshd
   sshd.service - OpenSSH server daemon
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/sshd.service; enabled; vendor preset: enabled)
   Active: activating (start) since Sat 2017-07-22 15:45:53 CEST; 17s ago
[...]
Jul 22 15:46:04 goautodial-7 sshd[1125]: Accepted password for root from 178.148.10.215 port 50034 ssh2